# How do I update the textField based on the PickerView values that are selected?

Tags: swift, textfield, picker

So I have an UIAlert and a textField attached to it. When I click inside the textField, a pickerView shows up and I get to select the day of the week. However when I select any day from the pickerView, the textField only displays the first value in the pickerView and does not update when I select a different value. The proper selected value still gets saved and the tableView is updated accordingly, but the text inside the textField doesn't change. Is it because it's inside of an alert?

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    let realm = try! Realm()

    var days : Results<Days>?
    var workouts : Results<Workouts>?

    var daysOfWeek : [String] = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednsday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

    var indexCheck : Int = 0

    let picker = UIPickerView()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        picker.delegate = self
        picker.dataSource = self

        navigationItem.title = "Workouts"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        let addBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addWorkout))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addBarButton


        loadDays()
    }

    @objc func addWorkout() {
        var textField1 = UITextField()
        var textField2 = UITextField()

        var containsDay = false
        var counter = 0
        textField1.delegate = self
        textField2.delegate = self

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Workout", message: "Please name your workout...", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let addAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Workout", style: .default) { (UIAlertAction) in
            //Add day and workout to database
            //if day exists, append workout to the existing day.
            //if day doesn't exist, create a day and append workout to newly created day object.

            //First, we have to create an initial days object...
            //Need to check if ANY of the weekdays == picked day, only execute then.
            if self.days?.isEmpty == false {
                for i in 0...(self.days!.count - 1) {

                    if self.days?[i].weekday == self.daysOfWeek[self.picker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)] {
                        containsDay = true
                        counter = i
                        break
                    }
                }

                if containsDay == true {
                    let newWorkout = Workouts()
                    newWorkout.title = textField2.text!

                    try! self.realm.write {
                        self.days?[counter].workout.append(newWorkout)
                        self.loadDays()
                    }
                } else {
                    let dow = Days()
                    let newWorkout = Workouts()
                    dow.weekday = self.daysOfWeek[self.picker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
                    newWorkout.title = textField2.text!
                    dow.workout.append(newWorkout)
                    self.save(newDay: dow)
                }
            } else {
                let dow = Days()
                let newWorkout = Workouts()
                dow.weekday = self.daysOfWeek[self.picker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
                newWorkout.title = textField2.text!
                dow.workout.append(newWorkout)

                self.save(newDay: dow)
            }
        }

        alert.addTextField { (alertTextField1) in
            alertTextField1.placeholder = "Day of Week"
            alertTextField1.text = self.daysOfWeek[self.picker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
            textField1 = alertTextField1
            alertTextField1.inputView = self.picker

        }

        alert.addTextField { (alertTextField2) in
            alertTextField2.placeholder = "Muscle Group"
            textField2 = alertTextField2
            alertTextField2.inputView = nil
        }


        alert.addAction(addAction)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = days?[section].weekday ?? "Section Header"
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        return label
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return days?.count ?? 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return days?[section].workout.count ?? 0
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        let workout = days?[indexPath.section].workout[indexPath.row].title ?? "Workout"

        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(workout)  Section:\(indexPath.section) Row:\(indexPath.row)"

        return cell
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if editingStyle == .delete {
            try! realm.write {
                realm.delete((days?[indexPath.section].workout[indexPath.row])!)

                tableView.beginUpdates()

                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)

                if days?[indexPath.section].workout.isEmpty == true {
                    realm.delete((days?[indexPath.section])!)
                    let indexSet = IndexSet(arrayLiteral: indexPath.section)
                    tableView.deleteSections(indexSet, with: .automatic)
                }

                tableView.endUpdates()
            }
        }
    }



    func loadDays() {
        days = realm.objects(Days.self)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func save(newDay : Days) {
        do {
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(newDay)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error saving day \(error)")
        }
        self.loadDays()
    }

}



extension ViewController : UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return 7
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return daysOfWeek[row]
    }

}
```

Comment: Unclear what the issue is. I don't see any implementation of https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerviewdelegate/1614371-pickerview so I do not see how _any_ change of value from the picker view would be communicated to your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your both textfiled object as global

```
var textField1 = UITextField()
var textField2 = UITextField()
```

Add pickerview's delegate method as updated in your code:

```
extension ViewController : UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return 7
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return daysOfWeek[row]
    }

   func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
    {
        textField1.text = daysOfWeek[row]
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare textfield object as global and use the method didSelectRow of PickerView to change the value of textfield on basis of selection.

**e.g.:-**

```
let picker = UIPickerView()
var textField1 = UITextField()
```

**Next, use below method to get selected value:-**

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    textField1.text = daysOfWeek[row]
}
```